# Centaurs, do they have control of their bodily functions?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, animals

We know that horses do not have control of their bowels when they march down the street. The question is... *do centaurs?*

Would it be a question of intelligence versus animal intelligence? Or is it a physiological issue?

Comment: Discuss question validity on meta here: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3679/scope-of-questions-regarding-fictional-species-appearing-in-rpgs

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually, from a strictly real-world biological point of view, we know that horses *can* control their bowel movements - they have two anal sphincters, one under conscious control, just the same as humans.  However, horses have two issues that lead to their defecating in the street:

1. Horses are typically not trained to withhold defecation
2. Horses eat large volumes of food that is not substantially changed by their digestive processes.

These two points lead to horses defecating wherever and whenever bowel pressure dictates.

Since some people keep miniature horses in their houses and successfully train the aforementioned miniature horses to not defecate indoors (See [here](http://www.guidehorse.com/housebreaking.htm)), it can be concluded that horses *can* be trained and maintain conscious control over their bowels.  The average horse-in-the-street just doesn't care where it defecates - and has a physiological necessity to defecate frequently - every 45 minutes or so.

So, to answer your question, unless the centaurs in question *want* to act like animals, even in the absence of any centaur cultural requirement about location of defecation, there is no reason why a centaur in mixed-species company wouldn't be able to learn pretty quickly that defecating in public is a social no-no, and have the physiological equipment to prevent inadvertent defecation.

In addition, centaurs may have a physiology that includes higher-quality food than horses - a humanoid-sized dentition, even if modified for a herbivorous diet, would practically necessitate richer food - which would lead to a greater reduction in volume as the food travelled down the centaur's gut, thus necessitating less frequent defecation.

Comment: I have learned a lot today about horse physiology that I did not expect to learn.

Comment: yea me too I did not think this would get answered but I love the person who did.